# How do I convert cue/bin mds/mdf to iso on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, conversion, iso-image, bin-cue-image

I've encountered a few cue/bin, mds/mdf files that I had lying around at one of my hard drives since the time when I was using windows, and now I'd like to convert them to Iso. I did some Googling, but only ended up more confused afterwards.

If there's anyone that got a good solution, please answer.

Thanks Albin

Answer (score 8):

Use bchunk and mdf2iso which are in the official repositories :

`bchunk file.bin file.cue file.iso`

and

`mdf2iso file.mdf file.iso`

Have a look at what you already have in your repositories with the `apt-cache search 2iso`:

> b5i2iso - BlindWrite image to ISO image file converter
>   ccd2iso - Converter from CloneCD disc image format to standard ISO
>   cdi2iso - DiscJuggler image to ISO image file converter
>   daa2iso - The DAA files (Direct Access Archive) to ISO converting tool
>   mdf2iso - A simple utility to convert mdf to iso / cue / toc images
>   nrg2iso - Extracts ISO9660 data from Nero ".nrg" files
>   pdi2iso - Instant Copy image to ISO image file converter
>   uif2iso - converts UIF files (used by MagicISO) to ISO or other formats

Comment: `mdf2iso` is not compatible with all mdf or mds files. Has not been updated for a very long time. You are better off using Windows software.

Answer (score 1):

If `mdf2iso` is not working you can use `audacity` (Import Raw Data).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

While you won't be able to convert a `.mds` file using it, `cdemu` will allow you to actually use them. There's good documentation on how to use it in the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/CDemu)