# How to really convert cue/bin files to ISO format?

Tags: conversion, iso-image

I found this here:
[How do I convert cue/bin mds/mdf to iso on Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/43733/how-do-i-convert-cue-bin-mds-mdf-to-iso-on-ubuntu)

And in fact, EVERYwhere on the web says to use bchunk in that way. But it does not work. It simply dumps out a bunch of files ending in iso01.cdr, iso02.cdr, iso03.cdr, etc. It does not produce a single ISO file. Does anyone know why, and how to really convert cue/bin to ISO? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you paste exactly what you typed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man bchunk`:

> bchunk converts a CD image in a ".bin / .cue" format (sometimes ".raw / .cue") to a set of .iso and .cdr tracks.

where `.iso` is for the data portions of the disc and `.cdr` is the audio data. There can be both on so called "mixed mode" CDs.

Furthermore:

> The .cdr tracks are in the native CD audio format. They can be either written on a CD-R using cdrecord ‐audio, or converted to WAV (or any other sound format for that matter) using sox.

and, if you don't like the `.cdr` format:

> -w     Makes binchunker write audio tracks in WAV format

You don't need an ISO image to write an audio CD. I don't know what you want to accomplish other than this, so probably you are asking the "wrong" question. You can write the audio CD information to disc with e.g. `wodim` which is an available package in Ubuntu, or Brasero which is the main graphical burning program in Ubuntu, or probably in many other ways.

Comment: Hmm, I don't really remember what the heck I was doing. I'll give you the point anyway though. :)

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack: That's understandable; I just answered since an identical question popped up recently and was linked to this unanswered one as a duplicate :-) .